# Can we limit the socks proxy only impact on one port or protocol, like POP3/IMAP?

Tags: java, proxy, jakarta-mail, socks

I use JavaMail to receive mails and JavaMail is only support Socks5. Receiving mail is just a feature that will be integrated into a big system. If I use socks5 proxy for JavaMail, I do not want other functions to use socks. Is there a way to limit the socks proxy only on POP3/IMAP protocol or let others can bypass the socks5 proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Set (e.g.) the [`mail.imap.socks.host`](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html#mail.imap.socks.host) property.

Comment: I know this property. But does it will impact others to go through socks proxy?

Comment: No, that's why it has the word "imap" in the name.

Comment: Using 'mail.imap.socks.host' and 'mail.imap.socks.port', it is not working, do I miss some property? And I am sure I am using imap not imaps.

Comment: What version of JavaMail are you using?  Maybe you have an old version before SOCKS proxy support was added.